# Reading a 6 byte, big endian binary field representing an integer

Tags: c++

I have binary, big-endian consisting of a message like:

```
struct Msg
{
    // 4 byte int
    // 6 byte int
    // 2 byte int
};
```

and I wish to read the 6 byte integer.

I haven't encountered a member before which wasn't 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes before.

I'm not concerned with portability, you can assume this is on a Linux system using GCC compiler.

To read this should I do:

```
struct Msg
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint16_t b;   // Part of 6 byte field
    uint32_t c;   // Part of 6 byte field
    uint16_t d;
}
```

and then do I `reinterpret_cast` the entire message, swap the bytes (to convert to little endian) for `b` and `c` and then multiply the value of `b` by `FFFF` before adding to `c`?

```
Msg msg = *reinterpret_cast<Msg*>(&bytes[0]);
value = (__builtin_bswap16(msg.b) << 32) + __builtin_bswap32(msg.c);
```

Comment: Believe me, the best way is this: `char Msg[4+6+2]; unsigned long a = Msg[0]<<24 | Msg[1]<<16 | Msg[2]<<8 | Msg[3]; unsigned long long b= Msg[4]<<40 | Msg[5]<<32 | Msg[6]<<24 | Msg[7]<<16 | Msg[8]<<8 | Msg[9]; unsigned int d = Msg[10]<<16 | Msg[11];`

Comment: You might have bit field members to not have 1, 2, 4, 8 bytes: `struct S { int32_t m: 24; };` But I don't think it is the right way to handle your issue.

Comment: @KamilCuk: `Msg[10]<<8`.

Comment: Are you sure it is 6 byte int and not a padding?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes it's honestly 6 bytes and no padding. The spec tells me the offset where the data begins and the size (6) of the data.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have said I don't care about portability. This is for GCC compiler, on Linux

Comment: Ouch, `pow(2,32)`. That's a really bad idea.

Comment: "Is it 2^32" you just cast it to `unsigned long` and left shift by 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is simpler and easier to write a function which will convert `int` of arbitrary size:

```
uint64_t readBigEndInt( const unsigned char *buff, size_t size )
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    while( size-- )
        r = (r << 8) + *buff++;
    return r;
}
```

and just apply it to parts of raw buffer accordingly.

Also thanks for @MSalters if you care about speed, make this function template:

```
template<size_t size>
uint64_t readBigEndInt( const unsigned char *buff )
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        r = (r << 8) + *buff++;
    return r;
}
```

so compiler can do better optimizations and you can provide specializations for 1,2,4 and 8 bytes if necessary. Also I would wrap it into thin class representing stream, that keeps current position and shift it by read operation. So your code at the end would be something like:

```
stream s(buffer,size);
uint32_t a = s.read<4>();
uint64_t b = s.read<6>();
uint16_t c = s.read<2>();
```

and so on.

Comment: I'd make `size` a template argument, so the compiler can unroll the `while` loop, or at the least define the function `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest non-portable solution would be to read the 6+2 byte members into a single `std::uint64_t`, extract the lower 16 bits and byte-swap those, and then byte-swap the remaining 6 bytes (which will neatly move them down into the lower 48 bits)

Remember to zero the lower 16 bits after extracting them.

Comment: What is the safest way to extract the lower 2 bytes of member a, along with the 6 bytes I want?

Comment: @mezamorphic: `std::uint16_t third = temp; temp&=~0xFFFF;` will remove the lower 2 bytes. You can then `__builtin_bswap64(temp)` .

Answer (score 0):

The only *portable* way to handle this is as Kamil suggests in comments, to use a `char` array of the correct size, and manually extract fields from the correct offsets. You can certainly write wrapper machinery to make this nicer if you're doing this enough to make it worthwhile.

For your struct approach to work correctly, you need a non-portable `#pragma pack` or `__attribute__((packed))` or other compiler-specific way to prevent normal padding and alignment of the members.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my Q to indicate I do not care about portability. This is GCC compiler on Linux, x86.